# Specman e: How to disable coverage of an instances / units?

Tags: specman, e, function-coverage

In my verification environment under `sys` there is an instance of `timer_sve`. Under `timer_sve` I have 2 other instances: `timer` and `ocp_master`:

```
extend sys {
    timer_sve : timer_sve_u is instance;
};

unit timer_sve_u {
    timer       : timer_u is instance;
    ocp_master  : ocp_u is instance;
};
```

I need to collect coverage only for `timer`.
I've tried this code (and many other variations of it) to disable the coverage of `ocp_master`:

```
extend sys {
    timer_sve : timer_sve_u is instance;

    setup() is also { // The code to disable ocp_master's coverage
        global.covers.set_cover_block("ocp_u", FALSE);
    };
};
```

The code is compiled and run successfully but it continues to collect coverage for `ocp_master`...
How can I disable collecting `ocp_master` coverage?
Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `set_cover_block(...)` doesn't take the unit as an input, but the module (i.e. file) in which the coverage elements were defined. Try changing it to take the file in which you extend your `ocp_u` with coverage definitions.

What I also do to disable certain coverage items/groups/etc. is set the `when` option to `FALSE`:

```
extend some_struct {
  cover some_cover using also
    when = FALSE;
};
```

Some speculation on my part:

Disabling coverage using `set_cover_block(...)` will probably not instrument the excluded code for coverage (i.e. completely ignore the coverage definitions) and make the simulation run faster than by disabling it using the `when` option.

Comment: The set_cover_block(...) method did not work also when I've defined the full pass to the 'ocp_cover.e' - Specman is compiled and running but just does not respond to set_cover_block()..(maybe I have not used it properly). But, I've succeeded to exclude the 'ocp_master' from the coverage by another method: set_cover("ocp*.*.*", FALSE);

Comment: @Halona Glad it works with `set_cover(...)`. If you're feeling adventurous and want to try `set_cover_block(...)` again, don't give it the full path to the e file, just give it the file name (without the .e extensions). That is the e module's name. As per the documentation, wildcards also work.